# global operator функция

Tags: c++, function-overloading

Как тут глобал оператор работает с данными класса? Какие свойство у него, и чем отличается от friend.

```
class Demo {
private:
  double d;
public:
  Demo() { d = 0.0; }
  Demo(double x) { d = x; }
  ~Demo() { cout <<"In Destructor" << endl; }
  double getd() { d = 5; return d; }
};

bool operator<(Demo a, Demo b)
{
  return a.getd() < b.getd();
}

bool operator==(Demo a, Demo b)
{
  return a.getd() == b.getd();
}

int main()
{
  Demo o1(2.0),o2(3.0);
  if(o1<o2)
    cout << "True";

  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Arshakyan  Вопрос не понятен.

Answer (score 3):

> Как тут глобал оператор работает с данными класса?

Так, как вы написали:

```
return a.getd() == b.getd();
```

(BTW, для double данный способ сравнения некорректен).

> чем отличается от friend.

Отсутствием доступа к private и protected.